# SSAS count of non zero measure

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am newbie to SSAS cube and need some help. I have a cube created from a fact table and one of the measure, lets call it amount, contains zeros. This measure was created as a SUM. 
Now I also have the Count measure added by SSAS designer.
What I need is the count of all non zero amount.
I tried to add a calculated measure as

```
`IIF([Measures].[amount] > 0,[Measures].[RowCount],null)`
```

also tried
    `FILTER([Measures].[RowCount],[Measures].[Amount] > 0)` 
Both these returns the count including the amount=0. 
I am validating it via SSMS sql query 
`SELECT count(*)
  FROM [dbo].[Fact_Session]
  where SiteKey = 5 and DateKey = 20170201
  and Amount >0`
Any help is appreciated. My assumption is that the IIF/Filter statement will operate on the individual rows before cubing, as once aggregated into a dimension, the amount will not be 0 due to the aggregation . Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

To count non-zero you can use this approach:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[IsNotEmpty] AS
  IIf(
   Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[Amount]))
   ,1
   ,Null
  )
```

But better to do this inside a SUM over a particular set - so the following counts how many subcategories are not empty:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[SubCategory_IsNotEmpty] AS
  SUM(
    [Product].[Product Categories].[SubCategory].members
   ,IIf(
      Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[Amount]))
      ,1
      ,Null
    )
  )
```